# Change Version While Running - Python 3.4 - Python 3.6.3

Tags: python, pygame, pyqt5, python-3.4, python-3.6

Quick question, hoping to write right.

Is it possible, while a Python script is running, to change the Python version?

Let me explain:

1. Script started (Python 3.4)
2. Open window in Pyqt5 (loading resources and others)
3. Window closed in Pyqt5
4. Version change (Python 3.6.3)
5. Open window in Pygame
6. Use of resources and other things
7. Script concluded

It's possible to do it?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: can't you do all in PyQt or in PyGame ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible (as far as I know) to actually *change* the running version of Python. And furthermore, I can't think of any reason you would have to.

In the *rare* circumstances where you might have found it advantageous to do such a thing (e.g. if you're using two libraries which are not both compatible with any single Python version), you can use something like the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to run a different version of Python in a separate process. You can either have it communicate with the original Python process, if necessary, or you can just have the original process sit there and do nothing until the newly invoked version finishes.

Comment: I asked the question why, I have a script in Python 3.6.3 and Pygame. I wanted to add some sort of loading using Pyqt5, but with the Python version 3.6.3 it does not work. So I tried to run the script using Python 3.4, installing Pygame, but despite all my best efforts, using different methods, I can not install Pygame for Python 3.4. So I find myself with two scripts (Pyqt5 in Python 3.4, Pygame in Python 3.6.3) that should be only one.

Comment: In this case I would suggest fixing the problems that are preventing you from installing Pygame in Python 3.4, or PyQt5 in Python 3.6.3.